# Why does using Nlog ArchiveEvery Hour kill my .Net windows service when Archive Every Day was working fine?

Tags: c#, nlog

We have been investigating an issue where the requests between `00:00` and `00:05` hours are getting processed with a delay. We found Nlog is trying to archive the entire day's data (10 GB) at the same time and is contributing to the issue. Archiving more frequently would avoid Nlog's overload and that could resolve the issue. What should be changed in the configuration to say archive more frequently rather than once a day?

I did change the ArchiveEvery attribute set to Hour from Day and observed that the issue is subsided. But, the service started to hang occasionally when rolling happens with the new configuration

As-is Code causing delay:

```
<nlog throwExceptions="true">
    <targets>
      </target>
      <target name="PointServiceHandlerMetrics" type="AsyncWrapper" queueLimit="5000" overflowAction="Discard">
        <target type="BufferingWrapper" name="file" bufferSize="120">
          <target type="File"
                  fileName="${basedir}/logs/PointServiceHandlerMetrics.log"
                  layout="${longdate} ${exception:format=tostring} ${message} ${newline}"
                  archiveFileName="D:/Application_Logs_Archive/PointServiceHandlerMetrics_{##}.log"
                  archiveEvery="Day"
                  archiveNumbering="Rolling"
                  maxArchiveFiles="3"
                  keepFileOpen="true"
                  concurrentWrites="true"
                  openFileCacheTimeout="600" />
        </target>
      </target>
    </targets>
    <rules>
      <logger name="PointServiceHandlerMetrics" minlevel="Info" writeTo="PointServiceHandlerMetrics"/>
    </rules>
  </nlog>
```

Below fix is attempted but causing the service to get hang occasionally.

```
<nlog throwExceptions="true">
    <targets>
      </target>
      <target name="PointServiceHandlerMetrics" type="AsyncWrapper" queueLimit="5000" overflowAction="Discard">
        <target type="BufferingWrapper" name="file" bufferSize="120">
          <target type="File"
                  fileName="${basedir}/logs/PointServiceHandlerMetrics.log"
                  layout="${longdate} ${exception:format=tostring} ${message} ${newline}"
                  archiveFileName="D:/Application_Logs_Archive/PointServiceHandlerMetrics_{##}.log"
                  archiveEvery="Hour"
                  concurrentWrites="true"
                  archiveNumbering="Rolling"
                  maxArchiveFiles="3"
                  keepFileOpen="true"
                  concurrentWrites="true"
                  openFileCacheTimeout="600" />
        </target>
      </target>
    </targets>
    <rules>
      <logger name="PointServiceHandlerMetrics" minlevel="Info" writeTo="PointServiceHandlerMetrics"/>
    </rules>
  </nlog>
```

I don't see the delay when ArchiveEvery set to Hour. But the service gets hang occasionally with below error.

Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.

> Exception Info: System.UnauthorizedAccessException
>   Stack:
>     at NLog.Targets.Target.WriteAsyncThreadSafe(NLog.Common.AsyncLogEventInfo)
>     at NLog.Targets.Target.WriteAsyncLogEvent(NLog.Common.AsyncLogEventInfo)
>     at NLog.LoggerImpl.WriteToTargetWithFilterChain(NLog.Internal.TargetWithFilterChain, NLog.LogEventInfo, NLog.Common.AsyncContinuation)
>     at NLog.LoggerImpl.Write(System.Type, NLog.Internal.TargetWithFilterChain, NLog.LogEventInfo, NLog.LogFactory)

Comment: Never use `throwExceptions="true"` in production environment. It is for unit-testing only. Make sure the user-account used for the application have write-access to `D:/Application_Logs_Archive`

Comment: If you activate NLog https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Internal-Logging then you will get better details of what is failing.

Comment: Thanks @RolfKristensen but can that cause the service to a hung state? What's the implication if I remove throwException?

Comment: The hung state is probably caused by some other application is locking files in `D:/Application_Logs_Archive` so File.Move fails after timeout. Again check the NLog https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Internal-Logging A workaround is to activate `async="true"`. The implication of removing `throwExceptions="true"` is that your application will stop crashing with unhandled exception and will not loose logevents.

Comment: Are you using NetCore or NetFramework ? Discovered a performance issue when using archive-logic on NetCore: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/pull/3691

Comment: Btw. you should remove the `BufferingWrapper` since it only adds overhead without adding any value. `AsyncWrapper` already ensures that NLog performs batch-writing to File-Target.